# Modelling Diffusion in Dymola/Modelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, dymola

I'm facing a problem with modelling diffusion in Dymola.
I want to have two seprate volumes (filled with air), which can be joined and thus exchange heat via diffusion.
My approach was using the Modelica.Fluid library and connect two ClosedVolumes with a Valve.
But as I found out, this library doesn't regard difussion.

What would be the best way to accomplish such a model?

Comment: I'm trying to make sure I understand the mode of heat transfer here.  Are you talking about thermal diffusion in the liquid or in the solid (housing of the fluid)?  If I understand you correctly, you've added a valve here to represent the fact that these volumes are connected but you are leaving the valve open, correct?  And so, you want heat to diffuse from one volume to the other?  Since this isn't convection, it is unrelated to movement of the fluid so you could just put a thermal conductor element between the two volumes.  Does that give you want you want?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply.
Yes, it's about thermal diffusion in the liquid. The problem with using a heat conductor, is that I'd have a continuous heat transfer. I want to be able to separate the volumes, that's why I used a valve.
I tried making a heat conductor with optional connections or setting the conductancy during runtime, but wasn't able to. (I'm not _that_ used to modelica)

Answer (score 1):

This limitation is due to the use of stream connector in the Modelica.Fluid library.

One way to solve this is to develop a fluid connector which do not rely on stream connector but only on potential and flow variables. Unfortunately in this case you'll have to solve yourself numerical problems for solving flow reversal and zero-flow singularity.

One example is described in the paper "[A physical solution for solving the zero-flow singularity in static thermal-hydraulics mixing models](http://dx.doi.org/10.3384/ecp14096847)" presenting in the Modelica conference 2014. Basically, adding diffusion helps to solve zero-flow singularity and they use a regularized step function to solve flow reversal. Other regularization functions can be found in `Modelica.Fluid.Utilities`.

Hope this help,
Best regards.