# Modifying .mo built-in files containing constants

Tags: constants, modelica

As a part of my studies, I am interested in modifying some constant properties of a medium like water. For example, in `Buildings.Media.Water` that cannot be accessed by Dymola (I opened it in Visual Studio Code), I am going to change a constant e.g. density. Is there any way to do so? or should I do it through partial medium?

[image]

This question is also applied to some thermo-physical properties like thermal diffusivity that I could not find it in the constants of water.
I would be thankful for your advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dymola you should be able to modify constants if you double-click the package containing the constant(s) and then edit the text using the Modelica-Text view. This way you should be able to edit all constants in the package. Obviously write-access is required to do so (which you e.g. don't usually have for the MSL).

Using inheritance (partial medium) makes sense if you want to be able to switch between multiple media quickly or you don't have write access. For experimentation it should be fine to directly change values - being careful not to forget to revert...

Comment: Thanks, your reply helped with first part of my question. What if I cannot find a property like thermal diffusion in package containing constants?

Comment: Not sure if you don't find it just because it is not there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408540/modelling-diffusion-in-dymola-modelica#28430345
I'm not very familiar with the Fluid package, so let's hope somebody else is able to give you a better answer...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the thermal diffusivity: it probably simply is not there. You could inherit from the original package and add it if that is the best solution to your needs.